# uploadifive on ubuntu Server with 500 internal Error

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx, uploadifive

I have a problem which makes my crazy. I set up an Ubuntu 1604 Server with nginx, php and laravel. All works perfect but when I upload a file with uploadifive script I got a unknown Error. When I see into google Chrome Browser I got the output:

> "Status Code:500 Internal Server Error"

On the Server I gave the public folder permission 775 and 777 but nothing works.

My Dev Server on Windows 7 with Vagrant box works perfect without problem. Any ideas where I could still look?

[image: My Dev Server]

[image: My Linux Webserver]

Comment: check the serverlogs from nginx and insert `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('set_time_limit', 0);` into your code to got all errors

Comment: sorry for the stupid question but where do i put this code?

Comment: on the top of your php file, under the <?php tag, to enable output error-messages.. The Logfiles you find under /var/log/nginx/

Comment: At the error.log from nginx is nothing relevant. With your Code i become this error: jquery.uploadifive.min.js:298 Uncaught ReferenceError: error_reporting is not defined
    at `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/vendor/uploadifive/jquery.uploadifive.min.js:298:1(anonymous function) @ jquery.uploadifive.min.js:298`

Comment: i wrote you should insert it into your PHP file, not your javascript file. Sure you got this error, this is an php function, not an javascript function.

Comment: ups, i forgot the ";" . Nothing happens -.- . Ich seh gerade das Du aus Wien bist. Vielleicht kann ich Dir das in deutsch besser erklären. Ich hab deine Zeile in mein WallpaperController.php in die erste Zeile (also nach <?php) gesetzt. Da zeigt er mir die Seite nicht mehr an. Ich mache wohl irgendwas Falsch :P .Bitte habe erbarmen. Ich versuche mich noch in der  ganzen Sache

Comment: Rufst du das ganze nicht über eine index.php auf?  Im Controller ist es vl schon zu spät. Ein 500er Fehler ist meist ein PHP Fatal error, es sei denn er wird ausgegeben.